# (Node.js) error while install exeSync using 'npm install execSync'

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I want to execute a shell command without callback, I know in Node.js v0.11 I can use execSync API,
but it's not a stable version, so I want to try exeSync module but there was an error while 'npm install exeSync', could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Where is error ? And you wrote "npm install exeSync" but correct module   name is execSync, so you need install "npm install execSync"

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake, I installed "npm install exeSync" and it was  "tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error with npm

Comment: Do you use proxy for connection to internet ?

Comment: Sorry I did not use proxy, ok I got it, thank you sir